# What value does an undeclared variable get in FORTRAN77

Tags: fortran

I am working with an old fortran77 script where a variable starting with the letter 'I' (indicating it is an integer) is used in a IF-statement, like

```
IF(I.EQ.1) CALL FUNC
```

without first being declared and a value being passed to it. So my question is what value does an undeclared integer get? The most logical seem to be 0 or 1. Thanks in advice!

Okay so this is pretty much how the routine works:

```
100 DO 10 J=1,20
    doing stuff
    IF (I.EQ.1) CALL FUNC
    10 CONTINUE

200 DO 20 J=1,30
    doing other stuff
    IF (X.GT.0) Y = 1
    20 CONTINUE
    IF (Y.GT.0) GOTO 100
    I = 1
    GOTO 100
```

And as you can see the I is first defined after the two DO-loops. So how does this work the first time when the DO-loop 10 is executed.

Comment: An undefined variable doesn't have any value, but there are plenty of ways `i` here could be defined and it's highly likely that something is being done to give it a value. A variable with type implicitly declared is no different from one with type explicitly declared in this regard. Are there compiler options being used, for example?

Comment: @francescalus Thanks for your answer. No the script is written in 1982 without any fancy compiler options. I have looked through the code thoroughly without any luck. So I guess, it is probably declared in a parent routine or something. What happens when the compiler tries to execute the IF-statement if the variable is not declared? Does it output any error or is it perhaps evaluted to False?

Comment: If `i` hasn't been assigned a value the behaviour is undefined - i.e. it is a bug, and anything can happen. In Fortran you can make no assumptions about the value of a variable until it has been assigned one.

Comment: Please don't mix up the concepts of _defined_ and _declared_. Definition (giving it a value) is the important one here, and where that definition happens can be difficult to track down. Without a full example of code it's hard to say whether `i` is truly undefined by the time of that IF statement. (And if it isn't, that's bad.)

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I will dig deeper to see if I can track down the definition in a parent routine. But if the variable is defined in another routine (i.e. file) can the same variable be accessed in the file I am working in without a COMMON-block?

Comment: There are lots of ways of making it defined, without more details it will be difficult to help you more - but if it is just a local variable in one routine then it is a totally different entity from any other local variable in another routine, even if the name is the same, even if the file is the same. But one idea - are you working with gfortran? If so you could, as a debugging tool, try compiling using `-finit-integer=99999`  and writing out the value of i just before the if condition. If it is 99999 it has most likely not been defined.

Comment: @francescalus I have updated the question with some code. It would be nice if you could have a look at it!

Comment: "what value does an undeclared integer get" It doesn't get any. The value is undefined. Accessing the value of an undefined variable is a bug. Always. After which anything is allowed to occur. There must be a duplicate somewhere ...

Comment: @jva The code is too incomplete. Really, **at least** you must show **the whole** subroutine and whole function. Look for any COMMON blocks or related entities. See [mcve]. If you want to demonstrate that it is undeclared, you must show the complete declaration part of the procedure. There is no other way. Look for any BLOCK DATA somewhere else.